# How to make filter list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make filter list which respond on user type. For example this is the list of data from the database.

```
<input type="search" class="search" name="search">
<ul class="find">
 <li>Bird</li>
 <li>Cabbage</li>
 <li>Cat</li>
 <li>Dog</li>
 <li>Eagle</li>
 <li>Egg</li>
 <li>Frog</li>
 <li>Fist</li>
</ul>
```

I don't have any JavaScript or jQuery code to show because I don't know how to do it.
What I want when a user type the first letter in the search box it will filter on the list. For example user type the first letter in the search box letter B it should filter all the list that start with letter B and it doesn't matter if the letter typed is big or small.
Is there anyone who can help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a model that represents the animals - or are you intending to search through the DOM? i.e. How is the list being populated?

Comment: I just want to filter all list that match on the user type in the search box. Just like my examples above.

Comment: I think @Spectric answered your question, then.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `input` event listener to the input which hides all `li` elements whose `textContent` doesn't include the input's value:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.find li');

search.addEventListener('input', function(){
  let val = search.value.toLowerCase();
  items.forEach(e => e.style.display = e.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(val) ? 'block' : 'none')
})
```

```html
<input type="search" class="search" name="search" id="search">
<ul class="find">
 <li>Bird</li>
 <li>Cabbage</li>
 <li>Cat</li>
 <li>Dog</li>
 <li>Eagle</li>
 <li>Egg</li>
 <li>Frog</li>
 <li>Fist</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `startsWith(val)` instead of `includes(val)` if you expect the user to type the beginning of the word.

Comment: Ivan Beliakov thanks for the info. Spectric thanks for the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

> The  HTML element contains a set of  elements that represent the permissible or recommended options available to choose from within other controls.

```html
<input list="animals" type="search" class="search" name="search">
<datalist class="find" id="animals">
 <option>Bird</option>
 <option>Cabbage</option>
 <option>Cat</option>
 <option>Dog</option>
 <option>Eagle</option>
 <option>Egg</option>
 <option>Frog</option>
 <option>Fist</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `forEach` loop:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.find li');
document.querySelector('[name=search]').addEventListener('input', function() {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.display = item.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase()) > -1 ? 'block' : 'none';
  }.bind(this));
});
```

```html
<input type="search" class="search" name="search">
<ul class="find">
  <li>Bird</li>
  <li>Cabbage</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  <li>Egg</li>
  <li>Frog</li>
  <li>Fist</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check wheather the textContent of `li` starts with the input text or not

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const list = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");

function showData(inputText) {
  list.forEach(el => {
    const text = el.textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (text.startsWith(inputText.toLowerCase())) el.style.display = "block";
    else el.style.display = "none";
  })
}

input.addEventListener("input", e => {
  showData(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="search" class="search" name="search">
<ul class="find">
  <li>Bird</li>
  <li>Cabbage</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  <li>Egg</li>
  <li>Frog</li>
  <li>Fist</li>
</ul>
```